# Wrap words to dash instead of space

Tags: ruby, regex

I have found a lot of one liner to wrap some text to complete words, like

```
text.scan(/\S.{0,#{width}}\S(?=\s|$)|\S+/)
```

Is there a simple way to make that work to wrap words ending at - instead of space ?
Thanks

Comment: Your question should post an example input string and expected output string (along with whatever your code example is doing).

Answer (score 0):

```
\S.{0,#{width}}\S(?=\-|$)|\S+
```

All you have to do is replace the \s by \-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the different answers, I understand that regex better now that I noticed that it was a small s, not a big one :).
Here is what I've used considering that :

```
text.gsub(/(.{1,#{width}})(\-+)|(.{1,#{width}})/, "\\1\\2\\3\|").split("|")
```

I used | for the split because I knew there wouldn't be any in the original text. Works perfectly :)